# Distinct values in linq with join clause

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have this type of code. In Material table it only have one MaterialId. But in Report table it can be multplie MaterialId rows.(One materialId can have multplie rows in Report table).

But in the Material table i do not have any Timestamp. But in Report there are a column as TimeStamp which I want to use to get the latest.

I only want distinct values with the ReportAdminModel as it is right now.

But how do I get it to work like that?
I have tried Distinct() but that does not work.

```
list = (from material in db.Material
                        join reports in db.Report on material.MaterialId equals reports.MaterialId
                        select new ReportAdminModel
                        { MaterialId = material.MaterialId, MaterialStatus = material.ProcessApprovalStatus, FlowIndex = material.FlowIndex, ActualStartTime = reports.Timestamp })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ActualStartTime).Take(item.NumberOfRows.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, try this :

```
list = (from material in db.Material
                join reports in (from rep in db.Report
                                 group rep by rep.MaterialId into grp
                                 let latestTimeStamp = grp.Max(o => o.Timestamp)
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     MaterialId = grp.Key,
                                     Timestamp = latestTimeStamp,
                                     //if you need any other field, just do something like :
                                     //SomeField = grp.Where(o => o.Timestamp == latestTimeStamp).Select(o => o.SomeField).FirstOrDefault();
                                 })    
                on material.MaterialId equals reports.MaterialId
                select new ReportAdminModel
                {MaterialId = material.MaterialId, 
                 MaterialStatus = material.ProcessApprovalStatus, 
                 FlowIndex = material.FlowIndex, 
                 ActualStartTime = reports.Timestamp, 
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActualStartTime).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just loading and loading and then I get timeout error. But maybe i can rebuild your code a little to see if it works.

Comment: This request should be pretty fast depending of the number of records you have in reports table. Do you have a huge set of records in this table ?

Comment: oh maybe i can do a Take before tolist because the table is very big.

Comment: The time-consuming operation is executed when we check all Timestamp for each MaterialId, since you want to have all materialIds..

Comment: I can't get the `ActualStartTime = latestTimeStamp` to work. It can't find latestTimeStamp @Florian

Comment: Hm, this is so weird. When i run this. I do not get them in order as it is in the database if i run order by timestamp desc in sql server.
In the database i have multiple values on time 2017-05-05.
But when I run your code I dont get anyone. The biggest time is 2017-05-02?

Comment: I edited the code to order by timestamp.
Can you make a use case and show it (edit your question) ? I'm not an expert but I think this should work properly, I'm maybe missing a point, we'll see it very quickly with a use case.

Comment: Glad to hear ! :-)

Comment: but there is one thing thats weird. when I use `Take(100)` before `ToList()` I get the highest date highest. But if i run `Take(500)` then all rows with highest date get lost. When I run 100 i get 2017-05-05 but when I run 500 it starts with 2017-05-04. All data from 2017-05-05 just disapper? @Florian

Comment: If i run Take(299) as the highest then I get all rows from the highest date in database. But over that. It removes the hihest date and adding the lowest row.

Comment: Why do you use Take method ? I mean, what is your aim ?

Comment: Because the table where i get information from is super big. So i cant take everything. I have a standard on 100 rows. But in the client you can change if you want too see more rows.

Comment: `.Take(500).ToList();` I do like this on the end of the code now.

Comment: I see your edited answer but there you do not have the Take()

Comment: Code is edited. You need to order by desc to get the max, and you need to do it before Take. so add your Take() between OrderByDesc and ToList() ;) Let me know if it does the trick

Comment: Nope, i removed the `orderby reports.Timestamp descending` and added the  `OrderByDescending(x => x.ActualStartTime).Take(500).ToList()` but it does not help..

Comment: Yo usay it does not help, what are the results ? I need to understand what is happening, because the code seems logic, and should work as expected. Let's take a closure look, try to edit your first post and add query results etc, we will figure this out mate

Comment: Yo, it is when I use take(100) i get all the latest rows. But if I use take(300) or more. It does not take the latest row based on timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `group` by `material.MaterialId, material.ProcessApprovalStatus, material.FlowIndex` and retrieve the last `Timestamp` data for per group item.

```
list = (from material in db.Material
        join reports in db.Report on material.MaterialId equals reports.MaterialId
        group new{material,reports} by new { material.MaterialId, material.ProcessApprovalStatus, material.FlowIndex } into materialGrouped
        select new ReportAdminModel
        { 
            MaterialId = materialGrouped.Key.MaterialId, 
            MaterialStatus = materialGrouped.Key.ProcessApprovalStatus, 
            FlowIndex = materialGrouped.Key.FlowIndex, 
            ActualStartTime = materialGrouped.Max(x => x.reports.TimeStamp)
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ActualStartTime).Take(item.NumberOfRows.Value).ToList();
```